# How to retrieve related instances without FK using one query in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Imagine there are three models named Movie, Actor, and Participation.

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField()


class Actor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class Participation(models.Model):
    movie_identifier = models.CharField()
    actor = models.ForgeinKey(Actor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Let's assume that I can't use ForgeinKey for the movie in the Participation model.

how can I retrieve all the participation records of a movie with only one query?

Here is the solution if I had a foreign key for the movie in the participation table:

```
qs = Movie.objects.filter(identifier="an_identiier").prefetch_related("participations_set")
```

How can I do this without having a Movie foreign key in the Participation model?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use a foreign key? Can you clarify the reason? Plus do note `prefetch_related` makes more than one query, only it gathers what objects need to be fetched and makes a query to get them all together, so there are atleast 2 queries made.

Comment: How do you expect to return the records of a table if it doesn't maintain a relationship. I guess that is not possible.

Comment: There are multiple models like Movie such as Series, Episode. Participation should have a relation to all of them and I don't wanna have multiple FKs. about prefetch_related, it only has 1 call to the database right? so you won't pay for network latency more than once.

Comment: @Moein you could try and emulate prefetch_related yourself: fetch all Participation objects related to any Movie (`Participation.objects.filter(movie_identifier__in=qs.values('identifier'))`), then loop over all results and append to a list on each movie. "I don't wanna have multiple FKs" is probably not a very good reason to overcomplicate things like this :)

Comment: @iain-shelvington
only one request will be sent to the database using this way? 
all elements of qs will be fetched? for example ```list(qs[:50])``` won't send a request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most important things when designing a database (hence when designing your models) is [database normalization [Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

You talk about `Participation` being related to multiple models like `Movie`, `Series`, `Episode`, etc. this means that `Movie`, `Series`, `Episode` all can be said to have something in **common** or they can be said to be a **specialization** of another entity let us say `Participatable` for the lack of a better word, or we can say `Participatable` is a **generalization** of `Movie`, `Series`, `Episode`, etc.

How do we model these? Well we will just have an extra model that our other models will have a `OneToOneField` with:

```
class Participatable(models.Model):
    # Any common fields here
    MOVIE = 'M'
    SERIES = 'S'
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (MOVIE, 'Movie'),
        (SERIES, 'Series'),
    ]
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

class Movie(models.Model):
    # uncommon fields
    participatable = models.OneToOneField(
        Participatable,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='movie',
    )

class Series(models.Model):
    # uncommon fields
    participatable = models.OneToOneField(
        Participatable,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='series',
    )

class Participation(models.Model):
    participatable = models.ForgeinKey(Participatable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    actor = models.ForgeinKey(Actor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Other than this solution which I find is the best for such modelling you can go with using the [content-types framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) which will essentially do what you do currently. That is it will use a field that stores the related id and also a foreign key that points to an entry in a table that will simply describe which table this id is for.